# Running `rg` in a while loop breaks after the first iteration

Tags: bash

My script is simple:

```
while read -r key; do
  rg --glob='!some_dir' --fixed-strings --quiet "$key" || echo "$key"
done < <(grep 'some_pattern' some/file | cut -d'"' -f2)
```

I hoped to use this bash script to print keys that aren't used. This loop, however, breaks after the first iteration at every run. Why and how to fix? Thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a *classic* signature of cases when the command run over a `while..read` loop starts from the standard input also. You expected the output of `grep` will be read over by the while loop in an iterative way, but for some reason your command `rg` is *also* reading from the same.

Close it as

```
rg --glob='!some_dir' --fixed-strings --quiet "$key" < /dev/null || echo "$key"
```

or use a different file descriptor

```
while read -r -u 3 key; do
  rg --glob='!some_dir' --fixed-strings --quiet "$key" || echo "$key"
done 3< <(grep 'some_pattern' some/file | cut -d'"' -f2)
```

Comment: How does your 3< work ? Is that redirecting the grep output to fd 3 ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew: Yes that basically it, instead of putting the grep's result over to stdin we do it to fd 3 from which the while loop reads from

Comment: That's useful to know. Thanks

Comment: I believe that the second form has the advantage to not interfere with stdin, hence is more "broad". It's a pity that this is not so by default.